# Bit Rotation Function

Tags: c++

I'm taking an online class that calls to create a function called Rotation that will take an object and rotate it count amount of bits. This is the code I currently have

```
unsigned Rotate(unsigned object, int count)
{  
   /*Initialize number of bits*/
   int numOfBits = CountBits(); 

   if (count < 0)
   {
      /*Negate count if it was a negative value*/
      count = -count;

      return (object << count) | (object >> (numOfBits - count));
   }
   else
      return (object >> count) | (object << (numOfBits - count));
}
```

the code for CountBits is:

```
const int SHIFT_COUNT = 1;  //Set bit shift count to 1

    int CountBits()
    {
       unsigned int uiValue = 1;  //Initial value to shift bits
       int bitCount;              //Variable to store the bit count

       /*Left-shift one bit at a time until the value equals zero*/
       for (bitCount = 0; uiValue != 0; bitCount++)
          uiValue <<= SHIFT_COUNT;

       return bitCount;
    }
```

I believe that my code is working correctly for the first two tests where it rotates by 1 and -1. However, when (numOfBits - count) is either negative or larger than the width of object, I'm being flagged for shifting violation error:

32-bit object shifted (>>) by 3217 bits

Object shifted (<<) by -3185 bits

Is there a particular way these types of shifts should be handled in my above code?

Comment: What does a 3217 bit shift for a 32-bit integer even mean? Do you want this to loop around multiple times? (Also, why is `SHIFT_COUNT` a named constant? This is a case where using the literal number directly would actually be clearer. And lastly, [there are constants in the C++ standard library for the width of integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits); check the `<limits>` standard header. No need to calculate this number at runtime.)

Comment: Hi Konrad, unfortunately the teacher isn't allowing us to use header files in this assignment. So we can't use CHAR_BIT or sizeof. SHIFT_COUNT was used due to that being a previous exercise where the teacher wants things done VERY specifically.

Comment: Fair enough, that’s maybe a bit silly but a reasonable specification for an assignment, I guess.

Comment: how on Earth do you need a header for `sizeof`? it's a builtin operator

Comment: valid point on that Lưu Vĩnh Phúc. It is a built in operator but, still nonetheless I can't use it in this assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to shift more than the size of the object. That means you should wrap the passed number in the limits ] -numOfBits; numOfBits [, because rotating +numOfBits of -numOfBits is just a no-op.

Code could become:

```
unsigned Rotate(unsigned object, int count)
{  
   /*Initialize number of bits*/
   int numOfBits = CountBits(); 

   count %= numOfBits;

   if (count < 0)
       ...
```

Comment: Serge, that worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Bit shifts of more than an object's size are Undefined Behaviour.  A conforming program shall not invoke Undefined Behaviour.

However, we know that when we rotate by the object's size, we end up with the original object, so we just need to shift by the *residue* of `count` *modulo* the object size:

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned Rotate(unsigned object, int count)
{
    static const int max_bits = sizeof object * CHAR_BIT;

    count %= max_bits;
    if (!count)
        /* avoid undefined shift right */
        return object;
    if (count < 0)
        /* force a positive quotient */
        count += max_bits;

    return (object << count) | (object >> (max_bits - count));
}

int main()
{
    unsigned u = 0xFF00;
    unsigned v = Rotate(u, 260); /* 256 + 4 */
    return v != 0xFF000;
}
```